# Lamport logical clock algorithm concrete scenario

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, synchronization, distributed-computing, clock

When and where is the Lamport logical clock algorithm actually used?

Can I ask for a concrete example/scenario?

I am interested in the scalar version of the algorithm (the simplest).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly answering your question but [dynamo uses vector clocks](http://the-paper-trail.org/blog/consistency-and-availability-in-amazons-dynamo/), which are basically a vector of Lamport clocks.